# SQL trigger on delete to implement reverse cascade

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables important to my problem here. Debates consists in several Arguments, which is a child of Posts. When I delete a Debate, I want to also delete related arguments, as well as the corresponding posts.

The first thing I tried is to create a cascade delete for the arguments, but this does not delete the posts. Indeed, this would require a 'reverse' cascade delete as the post is the parent of the argument. As suggested in [Is there any "reverse" ON DELETE CASCADE option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701178/is-there-any-reverse-on-delete-cascade-option), I then tried to add a trigger on the deletion of arguments to also delete posts, but this question ([on delete cascade not firing trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328570/on-delete-cascade-not-firing-trigger)) showed MySQL  'Triggers are not activated by foreign key actions.'

So I wanted to solve this problem by creating a trigger that does exactly what I explained in the first paragraph.

```
CREATE TRIGGER argument_delete BEFORE DELETE on debates
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM posts
       WHERE posts.id IN (SELECT arguments.id FROM arguments WHERE arguments.debate_id = debates.id);
END
```

As the arguments are cascade deleted when posts are deleted, this should work.

However, this trigger does not seem to work when a debate is deleted. Either I get the error saying there is a foreign key constraint violation if I remove the cascade delete between debates and arguments, or I get only the debate and the arguments deleted (not the posts) when I keep the previously cited cascade delete.

Does someone have an idea on how to do this?

---

**Edit:**

I actually based the delete part of the trigger on this question:
[Delete all rows in a table based on another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590799/delete-all-rows-in-a-table-based-on-another-table/37656639)

Comment: Do all of your tables have a coherent id, so that you can make joins between all 3 tables? Because then you can just join all 3 into 1 and make a delete statement on the id in question.

Comment: Yes, it is of course possible to join the three tables; I however thought it was better to avoid it for efficiency reasons?

Comment: Unsure, I don't see why that would be an issue though. I can try to look into higher performance-based solutions, but it shouldn't be bad performance by any means. sqlfiddle has been down for some time now though, which is annoying, since I want to test my sql's :S

Comment: Where would you use the join exactly? Would you still use a trigger?